# Get number of class by part name

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, replace

I have the element below:

```
<ul id="towns">
    <li class="clearfix odd 516_499_132_0_0 town132">...</li>
</ul>
```

I need extract the class "town132" for one parameter, but the number - 132 for example - is variable.

How do I for extract?

```
$('#towns').children('li').each(function() {
    parameter = $(this). // ???
});
```

Comment: Do you have control over the HTML that is rendered?  If possible, Id suggest changing it so that this value is stored in a data- attribute (e.g.. data-town="132").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know the class will always be there:

```
parameter = this.className.match(/town(\d+)/)[1];
```

Otherwise:

```
var m = this.className.match(/town(\d+)/);
if (m) {
    parameter = m[1];
}
```